# Include monthly counts including months where data doesn't exist

Tags: sql-server, date, select, reporting-services

This seems like it should be easy, but I cannot seem to figure it out. I have a table that has an `Artifact` name and `Modification_Date` among other things.  I have a query that is getting counts of document modifications by month.  There are a couple of months where there were no modifications.  Since I am querying and grouping on the `Modification_Date` there is no result returned for those months with no modifications.  Ideally, in the result set I'd like the month there and 0 for the `Quantity`.

```
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR(7), Modification_Date, 120) [Month], 
    COUNT(Artifact) as Quantity
    FROM table
WHERE Modification_Date > DATEADD(month, -6, getdate())
GROUP BY CONVERT(NVARCHAR(7), Modification_Date, 120)
ORDER BY [Month] DESC
```

This gets me a result similar to:

```
Month       Quantity
-------     --------
2013-02     10
2012-11     12
2012-10     5
2012-09     29
```

As you can see, the months of December 2012 and January 2013 are not in the result set.  I would like to have those months represented there with a 0 `Quantity` so that I can use that data in a SQL Report bar graph and have those months represented with a 0 value.  Currently on the bar graph it skips those months completely.  Is there a way to generate the `yyyy-mm` `Month` column for the last 6 months rather than just using the `Modification_Date`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't convert dates to strings to strip time or day, use date arithmetic. Converting to strings is less efficient and also requires a scan of the entire table.

If you're going to convert to a fixed length string, don't use `NVARCHAR`, use `CHAR`. What Unicode characters are you going to need to support in a numeric date? Umlauts? Pound signs? Hieroglyphics?

Here is an example that uses a catalog view to generate 6 rows, then subtracts months away from the current date to group by the previous 6 months (and an index on `Modification_Date` should be used, unlike your current approach). This is not entirely intuitive the first time you see it, but you can see my series on generating sets without loops ([part 1](http://sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-1) | [part 2](http://sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-2) | [part 3](http://sqlperformance.com/generate-a-set-3)).

```
;WITH x(m) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP 6 DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) 
    - (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])), 0) 
  FROM sys.all_objects
  ORDER BY [object_id]
)
SELECT [Month] = x.m, Quantity = COALESCE(COUNT(t.Artifact), 0)
FROM x
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tablename AS t
ON t.Modification_Date >= x.m
AND t.Modification_Date < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, x.m)
GROUP BY x.m
ORDER BY x.m DESC;
```

Note that this will not include the current month. If you want to shift to include October -> March instead of September -> February, just change this line:

```
+ 1 - (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])), 0)
```

And if formatting as `YYYY-MM` is absolutely essential, you can do this:

```
;WITH y(m) AS 
(
  SELECT TOP 6 DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()) 
    - (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])), 0) 
  FROM sys.all_objects
  ORDER BY [object_id]
),
x([Month], Quantity)
AS
(
  SELECT [Month] = y.m, Quantity = COALESCE(COUNT(t.Artifact), 0)
  FROM y
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tablename AS t
  ON t.Modification_Date >= y.m
  AND t.Modification_Date < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, y.m)
  GROUP BY y.m
)
SELECT [Month] = CONVERT(CHAR(7), [Month], 120), Quantity
FROM x
ORDER BY [Month] DESC;
```

Comment: That worked great!  Thank you so much.  You are right, there was no need for NVARCHAR.  I had seen a date conversion example that used it and used it in my query without thinking about it.