# SQL select multiple counts in the last 12 months including missing months

Tags: sql, date, count

I've been trying to create a SQL Query that returns a result that looks something like this:

```
May     2013    P1  0
May     2013    P2  5
May     2013    P3  2
May     2013    P4  1
June    2013    P1  3
June    2013    P2  2
June    2013    P3  4
June    2013    P4  9
July    2013    P1  0
July    2013    P2  0
July    2013    P3  5
July    2013    P4  2
```

The idea is I've got two tables Priority and Work:

```
Priority:
Name|Value
P1    9
P2    7
P3    5
P4    2
...
```

Work:

```
ID | PriorityValue | CompleteTime
1    9               03/04/2013
2    5               02/09/2013
3    7               12/01/2014
4    9               11/02/2014
```

How do I generate count for each priority work over the last 12 months or more?

So far I've looked at the solution from this [Include monthly counts including months where data doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237365/include-monthly-counts-including-months-where-data-doesnt-exist)

The query I've got so far is:

```
;WITH d(d) AS 
(
  SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, n, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, '20130501'), 0))
  FROM ( SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH, '20130501', '20140401') + 1) 
    n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1
    FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id] ) AS n
)
SELECT 
  d.d,
  DATENAME(MONTH, d.d) as [Month], 
  YEAR(d.d) as [Year], 
  Priority.Name, COUNT(Work.ID) AS Count
FROM d LEFT OUTER JOIN Work
  ON CompleteTime >= d.d
  AND CompleteTime < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, d.d) RIGHT OUTER JOIN Priority on Work.PriorityValue = Priority.Value
GROUP BY d.d, Priority.Name
ORDER BY d.d;
```

But it only generates a list of months with priority count > 0. For example:

```
May     2013    P3  5
May     2013    P4  55
July    2013    P3  8
July    2013    P4  48
August  2013    P3  2
August  2013    P4  8
```

Comment: What database ? (Oracle?, postgres?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone looking for a solution, I solved it using CROSS JOIN rather than RIGHT OUTER JOIN as below:

```
SELECT 
  d.d,
  DATENAME(MONTH, d.d) as [Month], 
  YEAR(d.d) as [Year], 
  ISNULL(Priority.Name,'P1'), 
  COUNT(Work.ID) AS Count
FROM d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Work ON CompleteTime >= d.d AND CompleteTime < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, d.d)
CROSS JOIN Priority on Work.PriorityValue = Priority.Value
GROUP BY d.d, ISNULL(Priority.Name,'P1')
ORDER BY d.d;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are grouping by Priority.Name which is null for items that don't exist.  To fix you have to give those a name (I used 'P1' below) and then it will work:

```
SELECT 
  d.d,
  DATENAME(MONTH, d.d) as [Month], 
  YEAR(d.d) as [Year], 
  ISNULL(Priority.Name,'P1'), 
  COUNT(Work.ID) AS Count
FROM d 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Work ON CompleteTime >= d.d AND CompleteTime < DATEADD(MONTH, 1, d.d)
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Priority on Work.PriorityValue = Priority.Value
GROUP BY d.d, ISNULL(Priority.Name,'P1')
ORDER BY d.d;
```

Comment: Hi Hogan, thanks for the reply. I've got the same result using your query. Below is the output sample:<br/>    NULL NULL NULL P1 0
NULL NULL NULL P2 0
2013-05-01 00:00:00.000 May 2013 P3 6
2013-05-01 00:00:00.000 May 2013 P4 71
2013-06-01 00:00:00.000 June 2013 P3 15
2013-06-01 00:00:00.000 June 2013 P4 35
2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 July 2013 P3 11
2013-07-01 00:00:00.000 July 2013 P4 79
2013-08-01 00:00:00.000 August 2013 P3 2
2013-08-01 00:00:00.000 August 2013 P4 8
2013-10-01 00:00:00.000 October 2013 P3 2
2014-04-01 00:00:00.000 April 2014 P3 2</code>

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to format code in a comment but the result looks the same with the one in my question.

Comment: @hihi - so how is that result wrong, you are getting 12 rows... isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @hihi or do yo want a row for every priority for every month?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Yes, I wanted to have a row for every priority per month as showed in the question. Anyway, I've solved it using CROSS JOIN rather than RIGHT OUTER JOIN. Thanks.